# Nuxt.js: understanding <nuxt-child> component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In Nuxt.js, I did this folder structure:

```
├── parent
│   ├── child1.vue
│   └── child2.vue
├── parent.vue
```

In **parent.vue**, I have this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Parent element</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><nuxt-child/></li>
            <li><nuxt-child/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

In **child1.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Child 1</h3>
    </div>
</template>
```

In **child2.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Child 2</h3>
    </div>
</template>
```

I launch the server (yarn run dev) and go this URI: `http://localohost:3000/parent` where I see this:

```
Parent element    
     - 
     -
```

If I go to `http://localohost:3000/parent/child1`, I see this:

```
Parent element    
     - Child 1
     - Child 1
```

If I go to `http://localohost:3000/parent/child2`, I see this:

```
Parent element    
     - Child 2
     - Child 2
```

**Question:**

From the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-child), I understand that **child1.vue** and **child2.vue** are children of parent.vue, so I expect to see them list when I visit `http://localhost:3000/parent`, but they were not displayed. Each child is displayed only when I point to its URI. Anyone to explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `<nuxt-child/>` is a replacement for the child component, *based on the **route***.

Using one is all that you need:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Parent element</h3>
        <nuxt-child/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then put what you need that differs in the child.

Edit: the child page is brought in based on the route. This is a manual way of doing [nested routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#nested-routes).

For example, say I had some events. The parent page is `event`, and then each event is a child.

```
- events
    - christmas
    - easter
```

When I go to `events/christmas` or `events/easter`, I’ll see the ‘event’ page but with the contents of the event I wanted. The parent page `events/` could possibly just contain a list of all the events for me to visit.

Comment: I am aware of all what you said, and I would like if you could elaborate on **based on the route** because I feel the real explanation is nearby there. Thank you

Comment: How can I maintain the nested uri of "parent/child" without rendering the parent page contents when I navigate to the child?

Comment: @JacobKochocki I think that’s more of a Vue Router issue, I don’t think there is a way of doing that